# How to refresh Magento Cache Management using CMD Prompt?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

How to refresh Magento Cache Management using CMD Prompt?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue with my self by the following solution.

Login to your server and run the below command from your magento root directory:

```
php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();'
```

Comment: I just want clear cache, what i need to put instead of flush();

Comment: Try this code Mage::app()->cleanCache();

Comment: Actually above code working for single website store, but if i try with multi-website store its not working. @Shorabh

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();'
```

Comment: May i know diff bw clear cache vs flush?

Comment: Clear cache only remove enable module cache where flush will remove all cache enable and disabled modules' both @Aveevan

Comment: I just want clear cache, what i need to put instead of flush();

Comment: rm -rf var/cache/*    use this command

Comment: I don't want remove cache folder bro, i just want clear cache in cache management.

Comment: this one help me, php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->cleanCache();' thank you bro.

Comment: Please mark as right answer if this helps you.  OR you can add your answer here.

Comment: Actually above code working for single website store, but if i try with multi-website store its not working. @Ravi Soni

Answer (score 0):

Remove cache folder:

```
$rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Comment: you mean remove the var/cache folder right?

Comment: yes!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I need to refresh https://snag.gy/BhVw4o.jpg

Comment: Once you delete cache folder, cache will be recreated (fresh new).

Answer (score 0):

**You can clear the Magento 1.9 or below Cache:**

> Magento keeps its cache in the var/cache/ folder located inside the
>   Magento installation directory. To clear the cache, simply delete
>   everything from the var/cache/ directory and then reload your website
>   in your browser.
>
> You can remove the content of that folder either via File Manager in
>   cPanel, FTP or SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before.  I tweaked it slightly so that it runs from shell directory.

http://ka.lpe.sh/2014/06/22/magento-clear-all-caches-from-command-line/

Web root

`clearCache.php`

```
echo "Start Cleaning all caches at ... " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n\n";
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::getConfig()->init();

$types = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes();

try {
    echo "Cleaning data cache... \n";
    flush();
    foreach ($types as $type => $data) {
        echo "Removing $type ... ";
        echo Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean($data["tags"]) ? "Cache cleared!" : "There is some error!";
        echo "\n";
    }
} catch (exception $e) {
    die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]");
}

echo "\n";

try {
    echo "Cleaning stored cache... ";
    flush();
    echo Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean() ? "Cache cleared!" : "There is some error!";
    echo "\n\n";
} catch (exception $e) {
    die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]");
}
```

To run

`php -f clearCache.php`

Cache isn't necessarily in files so clearing `var/cache` won't work for everyone.

Comment: This only works in single store mode.